# How to create a proxy on windows server?

Tags: networking, proxy, windows-server

I have 2 servers with connected with lan.
one of them got a internet connection with optional network adapter. second one is no internet.
I want to allow to visit the few website on second server by using first server's optional network adapter. Is it possible?

Comment: At the very simplest this is called internet connection sharing or you have the option to bridge the two network adapters. What has your research turned up?

Comment: How to be allow only one site block others on server?

Comment: Well you can’t with this method. But it wasn’t clear that’s what you wanted to do in your question.

Comment: I shared it but how do I connect with it on client?

Comment: The following link talking about how to share an internet connection, you could have a look: https://www.wikihow.com/Share-an-Internet-Connection#Video